# two ajax responses in WP

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am using ajax to load data when clicking a link in WordPress.
The request returns the response 2 times in one click.
The Code:

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_pt_add_to_compare', 'pt_add_to_compare_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pt_add_to_compare', 'pt_add_to_compare_callback' );
function pt_add_to_compare_callback() {
    $response = do_shortcode('[aps_product_specs id="'.$_POST['id'].'"]');
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

and the Ajax Part is

```
$(document).on('click', '.aps-comp-results li a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    var id = getQueryVariable(link, "id");
    $.post({
        url: ptobject.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            id: id,
            action: 'pt_add_to_compare',
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('.comparison-row').append('<div class="col-md-4">' + response + '</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

So Why this code returns the response twice?

Comment: is it not the first two lines above your function that's causing this?

Comment: I don't think so ... They are both required to do ajax request in WP.

Comment: console log the onclick event, see if its firing twice. You may have 2 event listeners?

Comment: I have tones of AJAX in my WP - never used this method?

Comment: @Jesse The console log also shows 2 responses

Comment: On the event listener? If so than that is why there are two ajax calls. There is an event listener on that element twice.

Comment: [SOLVED] Thanks all. It seems like I have an error in wp_enqueue_script. I do it twice for the same script using two different handles.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - Just a note, depending on the implementation, [`wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)) may or may not be required. the `nopriv` is functionally the same, but it allows it to be called for unauthenticated users (where a user isn't logged in). So it's not always necessary, but it's a commonly missed point in many "my WP Ajax isn't working" questions.

Comment: @Xhynk damn never knew that, I've just always put ajax in my .js files and attach to an event.. :S honestly never heard of the method used here